# manipulating web forms in python

Tags: python

I'm a novice at Python. I'm trying to learn how to post data to a web form and grab the result but I couldn't understand any of the examples I found on the web, and they pointed to websites that no longer exist. So I found this website http://www.autotrader.co.uk/vehiclecheck which accepts a vehicle reg and gives you some more data.

Can anyone show me how to put that data in the form and grab the text that then appears (on a new website)? I'm hoping someone can explain what the code does rather than just tell me the answer, as I just chose a random example (and therefore feel free to choose a different example). thanks

Comment: Take a look at the very popular 3rd-party module, [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.org/en/master).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a get request passing the reg:

```
import requests

params = {"SC":"132","vrm":"foobar"}

req = requests.get("https://www.vehiclecheck.co.uk/",params=params)

print(req.content)
```

Which if you run you will see in the output:

```
<h3>Sorry, we didn't recognise that registration.</h3>
                    <p>Please check that you have entered your registration correctly and try again. For example, a zero (0) and a capital O (letter) or a one (1) and a capital I (letter) can appear very similar.</p>
```

Which is exactly what you see in the browser.

Using  a proper reg you can see part of the html returned below which contains the search result, I removed art of  reg :

```
<div id="searchResult">
        <h1 class="HeaderMargin HideOnMobile">Vehicle details</h1>
        <h2 class="NoMargin HideOnMobile">We've identified this car using the details you provided</h2>
        <h2 class="NoMargin ShowOnMobile">We've identified this car</h2>
        <h3>HANGLONG UNKNOWN 2007 </h3>
        <div class="SearchResultCarImageContainer">
                <img src="/VehicleCheck/ShowImage/?id=&amp;CapType=0" alt="Vehicle image" id="searchResultCarImage">
                <p class="SubLine">Vehicle Image for illustrative purposes only.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
            <table id="vrmSearchTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Reg"><strong>Registration number:</strong></td>
                        <td class="Reg">GN57###</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Body type:</strong></td>
                    <td>Scooter</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Colour:</strong></td>
                    <td>Red</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Date of first registration:</strong></td>
                    <td>November 2007</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

If you were to input foobar into the search box in the browser you see a new tab open with the url:

```
 https://www.vehiclecheck.co.uk/?SC=132&vrm=foobar
```

You just need to mimic that with the request.

If you inspect the html you can see the form and what the input name is i.e `input name="vrm"`:

```
<form action="https://www.vehiclecheck.co.uk" method="get" target="_blank" class="js-top-form vrm-lookup-form">
    <input type="hidden" id="SC" name="SC" value="132">
    <div class="gb-reg-icon--wrap">
        <svg class="gb-reg-icon">
            <title>Registration GB Icon</title>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/templates/_generated/svg_icons/vehicle-check.svg#icon-gb-reg"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>

    <span class="js-vrm-input input-error-wrap">
        <input name="vrm" type="text" maxlength="8" class="reg-input-large input-large js-vrm-input-focus" placeholder="ENTER REG">
        <span class="js-input-error input-error vrm-mileage-input__vrm-error is-hidden"></span>
    </span>

    <button type="submit" class="vrm-lookup-form__button button-green-large track-submitVrmLookup tracking-motoring-products-link" data-label="vehicle-check-start-check-initiation">
        Start check
    </button>

</form>
```

When you go to the page after clicking i.e  the:

```
https://www.vehiclecheck.co.uk/?SC=132&vrm=foobar
```

page, open the developer console in chrome  firefox, open the network tab and hit f5, then have a look at the requests being made, in chrome you can see the first is `?SC=132&vrm=foobar` then when you click on that you see under query string parameters:

```
SC=132&vrm=foobar
```

Or if you click view parsed:

```
SC:132
vrm:foobar
```

Which are the parameters that need to be passed.

You have the input name so if you were trying to post, you would use the name i.e `vrm` as a key and the value you want to submit, using your own details:

```
import requests

data= {"vrm": "SM59TXS"}

req = requests.post("https://www.vehiclecheck.co.uk/",data=data)

print(req.content)
```

We see the searchResult again this time with your car details:

```
<div id="searchResult">
        <h1 class="HeaderMargin HideOnMobile">Vehicle details</h1>
        <h2 class="NoMargin HideOnMobile">We've identified this car using the details you provided</h2>
        <h2 class="NoMargin ShowOnMobile">We've identified this car</h2>
        <h3>VOLVO V70 R-DESIGN SE D 2009 </h3>
        <div class="SearchResultCarImageContainer">
                <img src="/VehicleCheck/ShowImage/?id=42B913362B14F8DF&amp;CapType=0" alt="Vehicle image" id="searchResultCarImage">
                <p class="SubLine">Vehicle Image for illustrative purposes only.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Column">
            <table id="vrmSearchTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Reg"><strong>Registration number:</strong></td>
                        <td class="Reg">SM59TXS</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Body type:</strong></td>
                    <td>Estate</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Colour:</strong></td>
                    <td>Blue</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Date of first registration:</strong></td>
                    <td>December 2009</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

So the bottom line is you need to find the input id or name from the html then post the using the id/name as the keys and the values you want to submit as the values. There is no magic bullet that will work for every form so you have to understand what is happening, that is why learning how to use the developer console will be be invaluable.

Comment: Ah the anonymous downvote with no explanation for a working answer

Comment: I hate them too. Perhaps it is because OP asked for 'posting' which implies a POST method. Anyway I'd use urllib2. For get is just fine, for POST as well with a little more work if form encoding is used instead of URL quoted. But generally I'd skip Requests for such simple tasks where session managing is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

One library for manipulating forms with Python is `selenium`.  here's an example of how you would interact with your given page with selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://www.autotrader.co.uk/vehiclecheck')

# find the input you want to manipulate by checking the source code of the website
# for example, to enter a reg, first ID the reg form by it's class

reg_form = driver.find_element_by_name('vrm')

# then send some input to it

reg_form.send_keys('test reg you want to send')

# then ID the start check button to be able to click it

start_check_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.vrm-lookup-form__button.button-green-large.track-submitVrmLookup.tracking-motoring-products-link')

# and send a click

start_check_button.click()

# then parse the page as you want
```